# can't find geth poA ressources

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ether, poa

I'm new to blockchain technology and currently working on an Ethereum project that requires the use of the PoA (Proof of Authority) consensus algorithm. I've heard that Geth allows for the use of PoA, but I'm having trouble finding resources on how to implement it.

Could someone provide me with some resources or guidance on how to use PoA with Geth? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have many tutorials regarding PoA (Clique)

https://github.com/ConsenSys-Academy/geth-poa-tutorial

https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/private-networks/tutorials/clique/

https://medium.com/coinmonks/setup-geth-ethereum-private-network-3806ef7fbe42